# Call api for every 1 minute(60*1000 milliseconds) upto 10 hours

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I am working on the app that runs in background and need to call api for every 1 minute(60*1000 millisecond) without any fluctuations. I have tried Scheduler,timer and things but it is not working proper. For example, my scenario is to call the api on 09:11:36 am(first api call),09:12:36 am(second api call) and so on and at the end the final api call will be at 11:20:36 pm. I used below code :

```
Handler minuteHandler = new Handler();
minuteHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
 // your runnable code
 minuteHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
 minuteHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);
 }
};
```

and

```
new Timer("threadname", true).scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
   // your runnable code              
        }
    }, 0,60*1000);
```

etc.,
My question is that it is possible to achieve in android(all OS vesions).

Comment: Where is the code you posted? Activity? Service? Some JobScheduler?

Comment: Hi @Pawel, I have tried the code in activity all well as in service.

Comment: Why do you need such a thing? You probably won't achieve that on any phone since battery will be dead in no time.

Comment: Hi @egoldx! Sorry, the things can't be exposed and the battery draining issues are not a problem for me in this scenario.

Comment: You need to use foreground service than.

Comment: Ok @egoldx, I will check and let you know

Comment: @Prasanth do you want to make api call even when the application is destroyed? or just as long as the application is in foreground or in the recent task?

Comment: @MRah, Need to call api in foreground and as well as in background(in recent tasks), the application is not destroyed.

Comment: @Prasanth take a look at this method and answer I have given regarding JobSchedulers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344220/job-scheduler-not-running-on-android-n/47760789#47760789,  Check out the Doze mode discussion, you will have a good idea. I will post something for you as AlarmManager is best suited for your operation in my opinion, take a look and let me know then I'll create a sample for you

Comment: @MRah Thanks. I will check this and let you know the feedback

Comment: @MRah I have tried the code as per your reference link, the scheduler works fine but the call back not triggering on particular time interval.

Comment: @Prasanth the job scheduler I posted will not help you in this case, it's because the next time api call happens is INTERVAL+JOB_DONE TIME, you have to restart the job immediately and then make the call. also it's not for doze mode, so for you setAlarmClock() is the best solution

Comment: @MRah While using setAlarmClock() the alarm not triggers on the exact time.

Comment: @Prasanth, did you log the lag time? Can you post it if it's available, I am going to look into this in more details today and update you

Answer (score 0):

Try AlarmManager.setAlarmClock (API 21) or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle (API 23) with a foreground service. This is the only thing I found working in background in Android's Dose mode.

Please note, Handler stops when your activity is paused or stopped and resumes when activity is resumed.

Not sure about Timer. but, I am sure it won't work in background when device is sleeping.

Comment: Thanks @Jia Li, I will check.

Comment: BTW, prior to API 21, try AlarmManager.setExact. It doesn't work in Dose mode but Dose mode doesn't exist before API 21.

Comment: Yes, Alarm manager not works in this case, I have tried already.

Comment: What is not working? You cannot start service with AlarmManager? or, you cannot do it every 1 min?

Comment: the problem i am facing is the second/minute fluctuations when the device is locked.

Comment: what about wake up the device a few secs before the due time. So the device has enough time to wake up?

Comment: Yes, In this i have used wakelock and full wake lock only supports this use case(the device screen gets on/off while triggering wake lock and the battery drains asap)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using service till api level 26 but in api level 27 service will automatically kill by the os.

Comment: Thanks Siddhesh. I have tried using service and handled the service without killing .My question is that need to call api for every 1 minute(60*1000) without any fluctuations.